# "EntityType 'UserProfile' has no key defined" but I have a key defined and it doesn't happen when debugging

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application which is based on the standard Internet Application template. I have created a separate class library with all of my database classes in and have moved the "UserProfile" class there and tweaked it a little as shown below:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid Email address")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have no problem using this class from my web application and it has been working just fine for months.

Yesterday I started writing a small helper console application which needs to update a table in the same database as the web application. I have added a reference to the database class library and everything is working fine when I run the application on my dev PC with or without the visual studio debugger.

However when I copy the application to my web server and run it from there I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'UserProfile' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserProfiles' is based on type 'UserProfile' that has no keys defined.
```

I have removed all references to EntityFramework and reinstalled it using nuget. I have tried versions 5.0.0 and 6.0.1 of the framework. Every Google result of the error leads me to posts saying to decorate the UserId property with a [Key] attribute but as you can see I already have that (it's there by default in fact)

Any ideas as it's driving me round the bend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working!

I had to set the reference to System.Web.Mvc to "Copy Local" so that it was included in the folder with the executables, etc.

I assume there is some global copy of the DLL on my dev PC that isn't installed on the server machine but this works so I can get on with it now!